# wmi.WMI().Win32_Process.watch_for("creation") ExecutablePath returns a blank value

Tags: python, process, wmi, executable, win32-process

I'm trying to log the path to the executable file of processes running on a windows machine using python. I'm using the following code:

```
import wmi

watcher = wmi.WMI().Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
while not stopped:
    process = watcher(timeout_ms=1)
    path = process.ExecutablePath
```

I'm running the same scenario (using an automatic test) and in some cases the value returned is blank while in others the path is correct. What can be the cause for this issue? How can I get the path to the executable file of the process?

I've also tried using winappdbg.win32 (get_filename) but encountered unicode issues.